# Error running a newly created MFC project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I created an MFC project in Visual Studio and tried to run it but it    got the error as shown in the picture.

this is the code:

```
   #include "pch.h"    #include "framework.h"    #include "MFCApplication1.h"
   #include "ChildFrm.h"
   #ifdef _DEBUG    #define new DEBUG_NEW    #endif
   // CChildFrame
   IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CChildFrame, CMDIChildWndEx)
   BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CChildFrame, CMDIChildWndEx)
ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_PRINT, &CChildFrame::OnFilePrint)
ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_PRINT_DIRECT, &CChildFrame::OnFilePrint)
ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_PRINT_PREVIEW, &CChildFrame::OnFilePrintPreview)
ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_FILE_PRINT_PREVIEW,    &CChildFrame::OnUpdateFilePrintPreview) END_MESSAGE_MAP()
   // CChildFrame construction/destruction
   CChildFrame::CChildFrame() noexcept {    // TODO: add member    initialization code here }
   CChildFrame::~CChildFrame() { }

   BOOL CChildFrame::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs) {    // TODO:    Modify the Window class or styles here by modifying the CREATESTRUCT    cs  if( !CMDIChildWndEx::PreCreateWindow(cs) )      return FALSE;

cs.style = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION |    WS_SYSMENU       | FWS_ADDTOTITLE | WS_THICKFRAME;

return TRUE; }
   // CChildFrame diagnostics
   #ifdef _DEBUG void CChildFrame::AssertValid() const {    CMDIChildWndEx::AssertValid(); }
   void CChildFrame::Dump(CDumpContext& dc) const {
CMDIChildWndEx::Dump(dc); }    #endif //_DEBUG
   // CChildFrame message handlers
   void CChildFrame::OnFilePrint() {    if    (m_dockManager.IsPrintPreviewValid())     {       PostMessage(WM_COMMAND,    AFX_ID_PREVIEW_PRINT);   } }
   void CChildFrame::OnFilePrintPreview() {     if    (m_dockManager.IsPrintPreviewValid())     {       PostMessage(WM_COMMAND,    AFX_ID_PREVIEW_CLOSE);  // force Print Preview mode closed   } }
   void CChildFrame::OnUpdateFilePrintPreview(CCmdUI* pCmdUI) {
pCmdUI->SetCheck(m_dockManager.IsPrintPreviewValid()); }
```

An error dialog appears
[ Unable to start program    C:\Users\PC\Desktop\WindownsProject1\Debug\MFCApplication1.exe'. The    system cannot find the file specified.]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvCiX.png [2]:    https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kib9c.jpg

Comment: Please show error diagnostics as text, not images.

Comment: I highly suggest you format your code properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program fails to build, so the executable is not created. That's why it can't be started.

From your screenshots it appears that you don't have MFC installed as part of visual studio. So you should launch visual studio installer and install the MFC component, then try again.

Comment: I tried to create a new project and choose MFC app again, but still it didn't work, I also tried to install different versions in the modify section of the visual studio installer. Why still doesn't work?

Comment: See this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-XB6geUQbTY 
At 3 minutes from start the guy is selecting what to install from visual studio installer, including MFC. Maybe that helps.

Comment: It should have warned you when you opened the project that the required toolset was not installed. Did you cancel out of that when it prompted? It seems you got it going, so that is good.